# Cadê os links nas páginas da central de ajuda?

Tags: bug, internacionalização

Estava vendo agora que a página https://pt.stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans não possui *links* importantes. Me parece que outras páginas tem o mesmo problema.

Ou precisa tirar o texto que não faz sentido ou colocar os *links* que existiam no original.

Claro que o ideal seria *links* para páginas em português, mas o *link* para a página em inglês é melhor que nada.

Página original: https://stackoverflow.com/help/question-bans

Comment: Concordo que ter uma lista de links úteis sem links não faz sentido. Mas a melhor alternativa é prover links em Português. Eu lembro que nós começamos um projeto pra traduzir o post do Eric Raymond. Poderiamos fazer o mesmo para os outros 2.